# NoSuchMethodError when calling method with var args

Tags: java

I have a method defined with var args

```
public static void myMethod(String sourceClass, String sourceFunction,
        String message, Object... args) {

 }
```

I am calling this method in two ways.

1. `myMethod(className, methodName, "List of all users : {}", userLists);`
2. `myMethod(className, methodName,
       "consumers of reqID : {} are : {}", reqID, userLists);`

I didn't get any compilation error but during runtime, I got below error for second method call whereas first method call executed successfully.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.MyClass.myMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V at

**UPDATE**

After debugging, I could able to trace the cause and fix it.

'myMethod' belongs to different jar.
when I compiled my application code, there was another below overloaded method exists along with above mentioned one.

```
public static void myMethod(String processName, String sourceClass, String sourceFunction,
    String message, Object... args) {

}
```

Later this overloaded method is removed and regenerated the jar and this final version is added in war pom.

**Fix I made is:**

I again compiled my application code with this final version and it is resolved.

Comment: Just use one Object varargs. You can check the length and cast later

Comment: print more your stack and add the code in the stack which call myMethod

Comment: That error means you are running with a different version of the class than the version you compiled against.

Comment: When I run this code with my objects at *Object...* , I got no error . Please add more code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and try to build again. Also you might be relying at a JAR file for compiling and using a different version at runtime.

Comment: Same jar version is bundled in the WAR.

Comment: Did you check the classpath? Just trying to figure out the issue one step at a time..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
myMethod("ClassName", "methodName", "message", new InstanceOfClass());
```